# Floating view (like in the Apple stock mail app)?

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, view, ios8

I would like to implement a floating view into my iOS app. Something like the one in Apple´s stock mail app on iPad when you write a new mail or the one you see in some apps as introduction (with the ability to be a fullscreen view on iPhone). Unfortunately, I cannot find any tutorials (maybe because I´m not sure if they´re really called "floating views"?). Does anyone know a good tutorial or a simple code fragment? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mail compose UI on iPad is an example of a view controller being shown as a [modal view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW3). You can get this style by [presenting a view controller modally](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:) using either the [`PageSheet` or `FormSheet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalPresentationStyle) style.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply place a UIView on top of your currently showing view. If you place it correctly you should get the desired effect. The animation likely comes from `[UIView animateWithDuration...` or some UIKitDynamics